On Mac M1, HyperLedger Chaincode install fails with error "dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
I am trying to setup Hyperledger Fabric (v2.2.7) in Mac M1 Pro and using Docker Desktop v4.32.0. I was setting two organisation network. I was able to setup Peers, CA, Orderers in both Organisations and all docker containers running properly. But When I install the chain code, I am getting below error.
Here is the error message
bash-3.2$ peer lifecycle chaincode install snb-chaincode-chitgroup-act.tar.gz
Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image inspection failed: Get "http://unix.sock/images/prod-peer1.regulatororg.snbchain.com-snb-chaincode-chitgroup-act_1-e57cbc6399c641f23b9fc09c8777213886c981ee483d545f47c89d1ce7662d9 n-38a9c951ca5cfece43263dd8043dc218f2cb9171cf38610474815d5bb595176/json": dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory
I have enabled "Allow the default Docker socket to be used (requires password)" option in docker settings and I checked /var/run/docker.sock is created.
bash-3.2$ ls -ltr /var/run/docker.sock  
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  daemon  44 Jul 20 18:09 /var/run/docker.sock -> /Users/sridharreddyu/.docker/run/docker.sock 
bash-3.2$

In peer docker compose files, I have this environment variable and volume mapping.
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/

and I checked the docker container
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer # ls -ltr /host/var/run/docker.sock
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            44 Jul 20 12:39 /host/var/run/docker.sock -\> /Users/sridharreddyu/.docker/run/docker.sock

Here is the One of the Organisations Peer and Orderrer Network
bash-3.2$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                              NAMES
999ebc7558fd   hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.2.7   "peer node start"        47 hours ago   Up 47 hours   7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8051-\>8051/tcp                   peer2.regulatororg.snbchain.com
3300f05a7636   hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.2.7   "peer node start"        47 hours ago   Up 47 hours   0.0.0.0:7051-\>7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:17051-\>17051/tcp   peer1.regulatororg.snbchain.com
2861dc96eba8   couchdb:3.1.1                   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   47 hours ago   Up 47 hours   4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6984-\>5984/tcp         couchdb2.regulatororg
d5e2d4fefd77   hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.5.3     "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   47 hours ago   Up 47 hours   0.0.0.0:7054-\>7054/tcp                             ca_peerRegulatorOrg
ba1374fad5c4   couchdb:3.1.1                   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   47 hours ago   Up 47 hours   4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984-\>5984/tcp         couchdb1.regulatororg
bash-3.2$

Initially /var/run/docker.sock was not enabled when Docker installed, later after going through StackOverFlow, I enabled that option, still I am facing the issue.
I think root case of the issue is, the softlink created b/w /var/run/docker.sock to /Users/sridharreddyu/.docker/run/docker.sock
When I checked in the container /host/var/run/docker.sock pointing to my home directory. I think container is not able to access my home directory from docker container.

It looks like /var/run/docker.sock is a symlink on your host.  When the container sees that symlink, it resolves it in the container's filesystem, not on the host.  (Are you writing any of your own code here, or just trying to deploy prebuilt software?  Do you trust this software with unrestricted root-level access over your entire host system?)

I am using the prebuilt commands given by Hyper Ledger Fabric software to install the chain code (smart contracts). When I run the command,  it looks like, it is talking to hyperledger/fabric-peer container and trying to start a new container with ChainCode image, that's where it is not able to talk to /host/var/run/docker.sock from the container as it is resolved to SymLink to /Users/sridharreddyu/.docker/run/docker.sock which is my Mac user home directory.  Regarding your question on trusting this software, as it is Dev setup, yes, I can trust it..

I think you probably need to just map the docker.sock location correctly rather than mapping the containing directory. This approach works for me on an M1 Mac. For example, with DOCKER_SOCK set appropriately:
peer:
  environment:
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  volumes:
    - ${DOCKER_SOCK}:/host/var/run/docker.sock

